# What is the right place to discuss SE site overlap or definition changes?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stackexchange-2.0, site-crossover

I feel I am close to a 3rd rail here, but as a general process question where is the "right" place to discuss overlap between SE sites and/or the possible need for site definition changes?

Area51 is clearly used for this for proposed and beta sites, but once they are launched they continue to evolve, new SE sites launch, and world changes as well.

There seem to be three possible approaches:

A discussion can be opened on the existing Area51 site page. It feels like the right place to discuss definition tweaks/updates, but it doesn't have a place for talking across sites and doesn't have existing sites (e.g. SuperUser). Perhaps it could be extended to cover existing sites as well?

It could be discussed on MetaStackOverflow. That seems to be a current common approach (especially before Area51), but it loses the context from Area51 for sites that did launch from it.

The other common approach seems to be to discuss it within the sites themselves like MetaSuperUser. But those communities will often have pro-community biases that may not be optimal for the larger SE community. And certainly they can't be used in the case of cross-community disputes on definitions.

For reference, here is a [MetaSuperUser discussion](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1631/it-annoys-me-that-theres-an-apple-se-but-so-many-apple-questions-on-su) on the overlap between the newer Apple site and older SuperUser site. In the end there doesn't seem be any clear, concrete criteria that a new user can use to choose between the two when asking a question or looking for an answer for most OSX topics, but each community certainly prefers their own site.

Also for reference see this [MetaSuperUser discussion](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5045/please-vote-on-proposed-changes-to-our-policy-on-tablet-computers) on adding Windows 8 ARM tablets to SuperUser. Its a good discussion, but its being made mostly the context of SU rather than the larger SE context (for example the [beta "Windows Phone"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) moderators are not involved).